# ClassNotFoundException on creating jar

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar, build.gradle

I am using Gradle as a build tool and IntelliJ IDE.

I have 2 local jars which I am using in `build.gradle` file as a dependency and picking it from local directory.

I also have a task to generate the jar for that project but when the jar is created and when I am trying to use it in other project it's giving class not found exception.

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.vodafone.tv'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    flatDir {
//these are the directories from where I am picking up the local jars
        dirs "C:\\Users\\debanjan.bhatt\\Desktop\\vtv-plugin-base-master"
        dirs "C:\\Users\\debanjan.bhatt\\Desktop"
    }
}
//task to generate jar
task buildPlugin(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': '1.0',
                'Plugin-Id': 'vtv-mqtt',
                'Plugin-Version': '1.0.0'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

dependencies {
    implementation(':vtv-plugin-base') // this is my first local jar 1
    implementation(name: 'org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.6')   //this is my seconds local jar 2
    implementation group: 'com.consol.citrus', name: 'citrus-java-dsl', version: '2.8.0'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20201115'
    compileOnly(group: 'org.pf4j', name: 'pf4j', version: '3.6.0')
    annotationProcessor(group: 'org.pf4j', name: 'pf4j', version: "3.6.0")
    implementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.4.0'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.30'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am getting the following error when this jar is created using the task and I am using it somewhere else in the project.

```txt
09:43:50,216 \[ INFO  \] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClientPersistence
```

Comment: Maybe remove the : in  implementation(':vtv-plugin-base')

Comment: the issue is not there

Comment: So, it seems to find the `.jar` files or it would fail sooner, correct?  It also seems to fail on the second jar, since `mqttv3` is in the classpath (an assumption tho).  So, I assume you have a `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.6.jar` file or somesuch?  Whatever your local jar file is, can you open that file (use 7-zip or something), and verify that `MqttClientPersistence.class` exists in it? Also, does whatever IDE you're using recognize the class?  Can you navigate to it (perhaps with Ctrl/Cmd + Click) whereever it's being used?  Just a few things to help narrow it down...